# How can I detect if the user (JID) is already logged in on login when using XMPP?

Tags: authentication, xmpp

In my chat application I want to implement a functionality that whenever a user is already logged in and if he/she wants to login again in some other device using the same username & password, it should revert the user back a message - "You are already logged in somewhere else"

I only know this method to check the logged in status -

```
connection.isConnected();
```

But this will not server my purpose.

Answer (score 4):

[Alex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623590/194894) is correct, but let me elaborate it a little bit:

After a successful login your XMPP-IM client will send a presence stanza to the server. The server then replies with the presence stanzas of ever JID in your roster with subscription status 'from' and 'both' ([RFC6121 XMPP-IM 4.2.2](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#presence-initial-outbound) and 4.4.2).

[Section 4.4.2](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#presence-broadcast-outbound) also states:

```
The user's server MUST also send the presence stanza to all of the user's 
available resources (including the resource that generated the presence
notification in the first place).
```

This means that you will get the presence information from every other connected resource of your JID. If you receive here a presence stanza from a different full JID then you used with your current connection **you know that a second (or third,...) client is connected with your JID** and you display the "You are already logged in somewhere else" message.

Note that this is not really what you want do when using XMPP, as multiple clients simultaneously connected using the same bare JID is *a core feature of XMPP-IM*.

When using smack, [`Iterator<Presence> Roster.getPresences(String user)`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Roster.html#getPresences%28java.lang.String%29) may be used to retrieve the presence information. The call would look something like this `getPresences(XMPPConnection.getUser())`. (Note that I have not verified if it really works).

Answer (score 3):

after login when you send your initial presence you get the presences of all your other resources (devices). So check all your incoming presences and you will know all your available connections.

Comment: I know we get all other connections, but how to manage those already connected networks. I want that when the person is already connected then it should receive a popup that you already logged in somewhere.